# [ros2] Launch file arguments, subsititutions, xacro and node parameters

Tags: ros, ros2, parameters, xacro

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I am having a "fight" with launch-file argument in ROS2 for a few days already. The scenario is the following:

1. Set parameter when calling launch file.
2. Use it as argument for xacro file holding robot description.
3. Use the output of processed file (URDF) as parameters for a node.

I managed to find a solution for the first two steps, but now I have an issue with the third one. The example launch file is:

```
from launch import LaunchDescription
from launch.actions import DeclareLaunchArgument
from launch.substitutions import Command, LaunchConfiguration, PathJoinSubstitution

from launch_ros.actions import Node

def generate_launch_description():
    declared_arguments = []
    declared_arguments.append(DeclareLaunchArgument(
        'robot_param',
        description='Some xacro robot param.'))

    robot_param = LaunchConfiguration('robot_param')

    robot_description_content = Command([
        PathJoinSubstitution([get_package_prefix('xacro'), 'bin', 'xacro']),
        ' ',
        PathJoinSubstitution([get_package_share_directory('ur_description'), 'urdf', 'ur.xacro']),
        ' ',
        'robot_param:=', robot_param,
        ])

    robot_description = {'robot_description': robot_description_content}

    robot_state_pub_node = Node(
        package='robot_state_publisher',
        executable='robot_state_publisher',
        output='screen',
        parameters=[robot_description]
    )
```

The Issue here is that "robot_description_content" is a string, and it cannot be used directly by the node. Only file paths are allowed. On the other hand, I cannot wrap this into a parameter map. Then I get a mapping issue.

What is the proper way to use this? Am I missing something with substitutions?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/373824/%5Bros2%5D-launch-file-arguments,-subsititutions,-xacro-and-node-parameters/) by [destogl](https://answers.ros.org/users/4469/destogl/) on ROS Answers with karma: 877 on 2021-03-11

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

**edit 2**

This is the full example launch file I was able to use to pass arguments to XACRO

```
import launch
from launch.substitutions import Command, LaunchConfiguration
import launch_ros
import os

def generate_launch_description():
pkg_share = launch_ros.substitutions.FindPackageShare(package='test_robot').find('test_robot')
default_model_path = os.path.join(pkg_share, 'urdf/test_robot.xacro')
default_with_gripper = 'False'

robot_state_publisher_node = launch_ros.actions.Node(
    package='robot_state_publisher',
    executable='robot_state_publisher',
    parameters=[{'robot_description': Command(['xacro ', LaunchConfiguration('model'), ' with_gripper:=', LaunchConfiguration('spawn_with_gripper')])}]
)
return launch.LaunchDescription([
    launch.actions.DeclareLaunchArgument(name='model', default_value=default_model_path,
                                        description='Absolute path to robot urdf file'),
    launch.actions.DeclareLaunchArgument(name='spawn_with_gripper', default_value=default_with_gripper,
                                description='Spawn xacro with gripper?'),
    robot_state_publisher_node,
])
```

**edit: I did not understand the full question, the below is not a satisfactory answer**

I think the `robot_param:=` is where you are having the issue.

You should be able to do the following directly:

```
    robot_state_publisher_node = launch_ros.actions.Node(
    package='robot_state_publisher',
    executable='robot_state_publisher',
    parameters=[{'robot_description': Command(['xacro ', <path_to_your_xacro_here>])}]
)
```

With the following imports

```
import launch
from launch.substitutions import Command, LaunchConfiguration
import launch_ros
import os
```

---

Originally posted by [vinny](https://answers.ros.org/users/52902/vinny/) with karma: 291 on 2021-03-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [destogl](https://answers.ros.org/users/4469/destogl/) on 2021-03-12**:
Hi vinny, thanks for your answer. I extended my question with the imports. Although this was not an issue.

I don't understand your answer: "I think the robot_param:= is where you are having the issue.". It there another way to set an argument in the xacro file? Did you test your approach? For me either way is not working....

**Comment by [vinny](https://answers.ros.org/users/52902/vinny/) on 2021-03-12**:
Oh I was not implying your imports were the issue , but regardless I originally misunderstood your question.

Can you please share how you are adding to the LaunchDescription?

I was able to pass arguments to an xacro using launch in the following file, but I am not sure what the full differences against your file are since I don't have the full launch file.

**Comment by [vinny](https://answers.ros.org/users/52902/vinny/) on 2021-03-12**:
I have edited the above answer for an example launch file I was able to get working. I was having trouble getting it to fit in the comments

**Comment by [destogl](https://answers.ros.org/users/4469/destogl/) on 2021-03-25**:
You answer is valid thanks! But actuall mistake was that I had comments in following format in my xacro file: "SOMETHING: xyz" and this was recognized as some mapping.